# Conversão em massa de encoding de arquivos no linux

Tags: linux, codificação-de-caracteres, bash, utf-8

Olá, eu estou precisando fazer a conversão de encoding de arquivos para utf-8 já que a aplicação ira migrar de servidor.

Nessa aplicação eu possuo arquivos com diversos encodings na verdade, alguns em utf-8, outros em iso-8859-1 e ainda arquivos em windows-1252.

O que eu preciso fazer é migrar todos para utf8. Eu consegui encontrar esse bash que faz isso. O problema é que ele acrescenta uma linha em branco após cada linha do arquivo, no caso, se eu tenho um arquivo com 200 linha, ele transforma em 400 deixando o código todo bagunçado e de difícil entendimento.

Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para evitar essa linha em branco que ele acrescenta.

Esse é o código que tenho para fazer essa conversão:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRETORIO=$1
LISTA="/tmp/lista-conversor.txt"

if [ -d "${DIRETORIO}" ]; then

echo -e "\nGerando lista de arquivos em \"${DIRETORIO}\" a serem analisados:\n"
find ${DIRETORIO} -type f > ${LISTA}
#-exec $DIRETORIO {} \;

while read ARQUIVO;do

        ISO_YES=$(file $ARQUIVO|grep 8859|wc -l)
        if [ "$ISO_YES" -eq 1 ]; then
                echo "iso-8859 detectado em $ARQUIVO"
                iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 ${ARQUIVO} >  ${ARQUIVO}.new && echo -e "Arquivo ${ARQUIVO} convertido com sucesso\n"
                cp $ARQUIVO ${ARQUIVO}.bkp
                mv ${ARQUIVO}.new ${ARQUIVO}
        fi

done < ${LISTA}

else
echo -e "Informe um diretorio\n\nEx:\n${0} <diretorio>"
fi
```

Comment: Adicione no seu script o parametro `-c` depois do comando `iconv` e ve se funciona. 

Vai ficar tipo: `iconv -c -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8` [...]

Comment: irei fazer isso @gfleck, pode me informar o que esse comando faz?

Comment: Certo, esse comando é o que converte efetivamente os teus arquivos. O resto do script é para automatizar o processo, mas aquela linha é o coracao do teu script.

Comment: @JoelPiccolidaRosa, não consigo entender o porquê de duplicar o número de linhas. Podes mostrar o `wc f` antes e depois da conversão? e já agora o `file -i f` fo ficheiro em causa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1

if [ ! -d "${DIR}" ]; then
    echo -e "Informe um diretorio\nEx:\n${0} <diretorio>"
    exit 1;
fi

for ARQ in $( find ${DIR} -name '*.txt' -type f );
do
    CONVERT=$( file ${ARQ} | grep "8859" | wc -l )

    if [ "$CONVERT" -eq 1 ]; then

            echo -n "Processando: '${ARQ}' ... "

            iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 ${ARQ} -o ${ARQ}.tmp

            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "OK!"
            else
                echo "ERRO!"
            fi

            cp ${ARQ} ${ARQ}.bkp

            mv ${ARQ}.tmp ${ARQ}
    fi

done
```

Comment: acabei resolvendo retirando o -e no iconv e então ele parou de remover as linhas em branco depois de cada linha do arquivo. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!